# Getting 405 - Method Not Allowed on some requests while uploading images via BlueImp FileUpload

Tags: apache, laravel-5, blueimp

I am getting **405 - Method not allowed error** for some requests when I try to upload images from BlueImp FileUpload plugin. This normally happens when I try to upload more than 6-7 images.
[These are the requests. Each request represent a separate file upload request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfABZ.png)

[This is the request headers, request and response of one of the failed request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWfsn.png)